# How to read the oldest unprocessed record in Kinesis Data Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I'm new to AWS and would like some guidance.

I want to process the **oldest unprocessed record** but I cannot seem to get the params right.

[Current Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZlYV.png)

For the shard iterator:

- I've tried TRIM_HORIZON which gave me all the records since the
  beginning.
- I've also tried LATEST which only gave me the one latest record.

Not sure if these additional details will help but...

- I'm putting my own records in through Lambda on the AWS console
- I'm debugging this by looking at the log files in CloudWatch
- I'm getting records through the shard iterator (TRIM_HORIZON and LATEST)
- My getRecords limit is set at 100

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try reading this: https://data-artisans.com/blog/turning-back-time-savepoints

Comment: It *sounds like* you need to preserve the `NextShardIterator` from the last [`GetRecords` response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetRecords.html)... [*"When you read repeatedly from a stream, use a GetShardIterator request to get the first shard iterator for use in your first GetRecords request and for subsequent reads use the shard iterator returned by the GetRecords request in NextShardIterator."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html)... am I missing something in your question?

Comment: My Lambda function which reads from kinesis only gets triggered when there is new activity in kinesis. Therefore, I'll get a new shard iterator every time the lambda function gets triggered as I'll need to invoke GetShardIterator again.

I'll try to see if I can preserve the NextShardIterator but I was trying to avoid preserving it in order to keep the lambda function stateless.

Are there any other ways I can do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "oldest unprocessed record", as Kinesis doesn't know what you've processed (for example, you may have fetched the records but not done anything with them).

If you're using Kinesis, I *strongly* recommend using [Kinesis Client Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-consumers-with-kcl.html), which has the concept of [checkpoints](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/clientlibrary/interfaces/IRecordProcessorCheckpointer.java) - these are essentially a nice wrapper on top of [ShardIterator AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html#API_GetShardIterator_RequestSyntax), which translates to "oldest uncheckpointed record" - or as close as you'll get to "oldest unprocessed record".

(You could always implement this logic yourself, but why not reuse work that Amazon has already done for you?)

Comment: Ah yes. I was looking at KCL. However, I still cannot figure out how to make it work with Lambda. Maybe I'll have to spin up an EC2 instance instead.

Comment: Yep, KCL will require a host to run on; EC2 will do that for you.  Probably way more cost effective too, unless your shards are _very_ low traffic (in which case, there are more cost effective solutions than Kinesis)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance! One last thing, my shards are quite low traffic. What are these "more cost effective solutions than Kinesis" that you speak of?

Comment: At it's core, think of Kinesis as a queue. It's a queue that you can do some fancy things with, especially at high volume, but for low volumes there are other things that act as a 'queue' just as well (with slightly different features - choose based on your needs).  SQS & SNS are the more obvious AWS based choices.

Comment: Ah. I'll read that up. Thanks a lot to everyone who contributed! :)